# Gridview within gridview to have fixed header and pager using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, cross-browser

I have built a GridView in which each row has a GridView. So for the top most GridView i want to header and pager to be fixed so that only its content can be scrolled using jquery. I have tried various scripts from Google. Some work and some don't. The ones which work have browser incompatibility. So i need cross browser solution. Please give me an working example.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMasterGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="odsMasterGrid" OnRowDataBound="gvMasterGrid_RowDataBound" PageSize="3"
            AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvMasterGrid_PageIndexChanging" OnPreRender="gvMasterGrid_PreRender">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <img alt="" id="plus" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.jpg" width="20px"
            height="20px" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildGrid" runat="server" Style="display: none">
          <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CssClass="subgridview">
          </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
  </Columns>
  <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want gvMasterGrid to have fixed header and footer. The rows of gvMasterGrid should be scrollable.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code in order for a proper solution to be offered. As it stands, the problem is too ambiguous

Comment: Hi brian, i have added the sample code.